# NodeJs asynchronous error handler controller. Why does original function need to be wrapped by another function?

Tags: node.js, express

```
module.exports = catchAsync = (fn) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch((err) => {
      next(err);
    });
  };
};
```

I'm confused on why fn.(req,res,next).catch(err) needs to be wrapped by another anonymous function. In this case, I'm using this as an error handler for my rest api's controller functions. Im confused on why fn.catch can't just be returned directly.

I tried directly returning the fn.catch, although that didn't seem to work.